# Saving an Arraycollection field to mysql/php using actionscript

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, actionscript-3

How do you save an arraycollection field in an object to a mysql database. I usually would have used a for each item in array collection field then pass a unique key to it so it track it back later, but thats getting cumbersome now. 
Is there a way to save an arraycollection that also allows easy update of the arraycollection item.

Thanks in advance

Johnny

Comment: Your explanation isn't very clear.  Are you trying to have some kind of persistence between Flex and the DB on a particular entity within an ArrayCollection?

Answer (score 1):

If you woun't update some elements of collection separately, you may store it in one row (values of array separated with ',' in one string). Use blob fields if the string will be long. If you need to update some part in that collection you may tre to derive out that part in separate row. But it's not good practice, so if you want to update something putting each element of collection in a separate field is probably the best solution.